# proguard-rules "-dontwarn" not working (AGP 8.0)

Tags: android, realm, proguard, android-r8, android-gradle-plugin-8.0

After updating to Android Gradle Plugin 8.0, I get the following build-time errors during the minifyReleaseAndroidTestWithR8 step:

> Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\...\app\build\outputs\mapping\releaseAndroidTest\missing_rules.txt.

> Missing class io.reactivex.Flowable (referenced from: io.reactivex.Flowable io.realm.BaseRealm.asFlowable() and 5 other contexts)
>
> Missing class io.reactivex.Observable (referenced from:
> io.reactivex.Observable io.realm.RealmList.asChangesetObservable() and
> 3 other contexts)
>
> Missing class java.lang.ClassValue (referenced from:
> java.lang.ClassValue
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.FuturesGetChecked$GetCheckedTypeValidatorHolder$ClassValueValidator.isValidClass
> and 3 other contexts)

I understand that prior to AGP 8.0 missing classes were treated as warnings, and now they are errors.  So I added the rules from the `missing_rules.txt` file to my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn io.reactivex.Flowable
-dontwarn io.reactivex.Observable
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
```

However, the newly-added `-dontwarn` rules seem to have no effect.  I get the same "Missing class" errors on subsequent builds.  I have tried building after cleaning the project, building after restarting Android Studio, and building after invalidating Android Studio's cache.  All to no avail.

I have also tried adding ".**" to each rule.  I still get the same "Missing class" errors.

My `proguard-rules` file has another `-dontwarn` rule which *does* work:

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Cleaner
```

If I remove this rule, I get a missing class warning for `sun.misc.Cleaner` (as expected), and if I re-instate the rule, the error goes away.  This would appear to indicate that the problem is not a fundamental problem with `-dontwarn` rules.

If I disable `minifyEnabled`, the build completes without error.

Two of the three missing (`io.reactivex`) classes are referenced from Realm classes.  Not sure if that is significant.

I've run out of things to try, and would welcome any thoughts/suggestions.

Thanks for reading.

---

### proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Cleaner                      # this one works

-dontwarn io.reactivex.Flowable                 # has no effect
-dontwarn io.reactivex.Observable               # has no effect
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue                  # has no effect

# don't obfuscate field names of RealmObjects that are imported/exported via JSON
# e.g. design & project, and their sub-ordinate classes
-keep class com.something.model.design.** { <fields>; }
-keep class com.something.model.project.** { <fields>; }

# don't obfuscate the fields in BracingButtonBar's ViewBinding class
-keep class com.something.databinding.BracingButtonBarBinding { <fields>; }
# Without this: BracingButtonBarBinding.class.getDeclaredFields() will not
# return the fields for the CheckImageButtons.
# This breaks BracingButtonBar.getButtons().

# don't obfuscate the fields in FretboardValuesDialog's ViewBinding class
-keep class com.something.databinding.FretboardValuesDialogBinding { <fields>; }
# Without this: will crash when raising the FretboardValuesDialog.

-keepattributes *Annotation*, Exceptions

# retain source file names and line numbers in stack traces
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable

# de-obfuscating within inner classes doesn't seem to work, maybe this will help?
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message refers to `releaseAndroidTest` the error seems to come from building the test and not the app.

You will then have to add the `-dontwarn` rules to the `testProguardFiles` alongside your `proguardFiles`, something like this:

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles
                getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
            testProguardFiles 'test-proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

See https://issuetracker.google.com/260300637 for more context.

Comment: That works!  Thank you very much.  I was not familiar with the 'testProguardFiles' method.

I had resorted to turning off fullMode, but this is a far better solution.